# Thanks yenaled!

Tags: phrases, uncountable-nouns

Is "yenaled" a word in English? If yes, kindly, give me its example from any certified dictionary.

My context is:

One of my friends was teaching the students on Facebook about this word. As I looked up this in certified dictionaries. I didn't find anything. Result not found!

But as I used Google for this word; I only got one thing – this was: ( Yenaled means a lot of) and it is uncountable noun.

So he was teaching the students about "yenaled". Thanks yenaled. I was very much confused to see, " thanks yenaled".

Comment: As a reminder, it is April Fool’s Day. There have been yenaled fake posts going around. Was this post from today?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, **yenaled** is not an English word, that is for sure.

However, this coincidence is interesting - read backwards, you will get:

> [Delaney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaney)

which is definitely an (english?) name.

So:

> Thanks yenaled!

might actually mean:

> Thanks, Delaney!

Answer (score 1):

New words and new meanings of words will enter the language before they appear in dictionaries, so it's not impossible that this is a newly emerging word. However [this definition](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/yenaled), which I guess is the one you found, lacks citations and does not seem convincing to me.

I have never heard or used **yenaled**, if you want to be understood don't use it.

Comment: Agreed, if my comment wasn't clear, I was completely joking. I've never heard of "yenaled" and have no idea what it would mean.

Answer (score 1):

Yenaled is NOT an English word. Your source is an "online slang dictionary". Yenaled is Delaney backwards, but no one refers to another as backwards. Also my name is Delaney. Also there is no word in English for "a lot of".